# Elasticsearch - buckets_path agg on terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to do AVG count of terms (count_bucket) but I have an error:

```
"buckets_path must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation, got: [Bucket] at aggregation [count_bucket]"
```

Here is my query: Where count_bucket is count term agg and I want avg of this.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    track_total_hits: true,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": queries,
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": supress
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "count_bucket": {
            "terms": {
                "field": field,
                "size": 500,
                "order": {
                    "_key": "desc"
                }
            }
        },
        "avg_count": {
              "avg_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "count_bucket" 
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is described in the error message: term aggregation does not return a single value, unlike other aggregation such as `sum` or `value_count`. Therefore you can not perform `avg_bucket` aggregation on those buckets.

A good solution is to use `value_count` aggregation on each bucket to return a single value, on which you can then do the `avg_bucket` aggregation:

Here's how it looks:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": queries,
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": supress
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "count_bucket": {
            "terms": {
                "field": field,
                "size": 500,
                "order": {
                    "_key": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "docs_count": {
                    "value_count": {
                        "field": field
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "avg_count": {
                "avg_bucket": {
                    "buckets_path": "count_bucket>docs_count"
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I can't use count agg on term. But it used on docs_count, I see now.